# .htaccess redirect url excluding certain subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect my WordPress multisite root site to another page, but I still want to be able to access `/wp-admin`, `/wp-login` and `/wp-json`.

When I go to the browser I want `url.com` to redirect to `newurl.com` UNLESS it has one of the above directories on the end.

This is what I've come up with but when I go to the browser and enter `url.com` it loads the page as usual. Where am I going wrong?

Note: The block at the bottom is where the redirect should be happening.

```
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force SSL / HTTPS
# Note: X-Forwarded-Proto is required for AWS's Elastic Load Balancing.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# This is the block that should redirect, but isn't.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^url\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/wp-admin$|/wp-login$|/wp-json$)
RewriteRule ^ http://newurl.com/ [R=301]
```

Comment: `doesn't seem to work`. Can you be more specific ? What was the url you tried ?

Comment: I'm trying to access `url.com` but it just loads the page as usual, I've updated the question to make it a little more clear.

Comment: It seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule was working fine.
You did not see it because it was never reached due to its position in the htaccess.

Actually, you need to place your rule **before** the `default`-last rule, otherwise it won't never be executed.

```
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force SSL / HTTPS
# Note: X-Forwarded-Proto is required for AWS's Elastic Load Balancing.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

# This is the block that should redirect, but isn't.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^url\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/wp-admin$|/wp-login$|/wp-json$)
RewriteRule ^ http://newurl.com/ [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine for me. I changed a few things on the condition and added, the `L` flag to make sure it stops when the rule is met. Make sure your .htaccess file is being read. You can verify your apache config file has `AllowOverride All` or it won't read your htaccess file.

```
Options -FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^url\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp-admin|wp-login|wp-json)$
RewriteRule ^ http://newurl.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'm assuming that it's not hitting those lines - .htaccess is definitely working though - see my updated question, I added the other directed I have above it (the ones above work correctly.)

Comment: Are there multiple sites on there? If this is in the doc root of `url.com` you really don't need that condition to check if the host is `url.com`. Also try putting this above the other rules.

Comment: It's a WordPress multisite site, so yeah, there are multiple sites - I want my root site to redirect elsewhere whilst still being able to access it's admin pages.